# What do you do when the OP copies your answer and posts it as his own?

Tags: discussion, unaccepted-answer

I just had one of my answers unaccepted, I checked the question and noticed that what the OP had done was unaccept my answer so that he could accept his own answer, which used the exact styles that I had provided in my answer to help him achieve the functionality he was looking for. Is that allowed?

Comment: Do you have links? You can edit the reference to the answer into his answer.

Comment: sometimes those looking for cut-and-paste answers think *they* have Discovered the Answer because they had to add an `if` or something else trivial to your answer.  It happens

Comment: He didn't even copy and paste it properly, he wrapped styles in script tags...

Comment: He didn't even copy and paste it properly, period.  I'd just move on.  Nothing more to see here.

Comment: @ShemSeger: It's not even the same answer? There are parts that are similar.

Comment: He used the styles I gave him. All he did was was change the selector name, width value, and delete the border, then he wrapped it in <script> tags for some reason...

Comment: Which makes it no longer a copy/paste.

Comment: @ShemSeger: It's still different by about 80%

Comment: So it's ok to copy someones answer as long as you tweak it enough so that it isn't an exact copy/paste?

Comment: It's just some CSS styles.  Everything on the site is CC:Wiki anyway, so if you're surprised that someone would lift your code, make some changes, and repost it so others can see the differences, well...

Comment: I know it's something small and petty, but I'd still like to know what to do in the future.

Comment: In the future, consider the magnitude of the problem when evaluating what to do.

Comment: I can understand your frustration of having your correct answer unaccepted, but you kinda twisted reality big time here. I saw nothing that was "exact code" or "literally copied".

Comment: @gitsitgo My styles: `width:12em;white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;` "His" styles: `width:50px;white-space: nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;` Please explain to me how these are not the same, besides the arbitrary width value.

Comment: @Robert Harvey My situation aside, supposing the OP had blatantly stolen your accepted answer and posted it as his own, then unaccepted your answer so he (or she) could accept the copy they had posted, what would you recommend be done?

Comment: @ShemSeger Yes, he got his code mostly from you, but is the code literally copied? No. Is the answer literally copied? No. Furthermore, he put the styles in a class selector, which is different (and arguably makes more sense than your answer because you can reuse classes unlike id selectors). Once again, I am almost certain that he did use your answer so I can see why anyone would be frustrated in this case, but when it comes to the accepted answer, OP usually has final say as long as its not a direct rip.

Comment: So then the answer is it depends on what the community thinks.

Answer (score 4):

> If a user is word-for-word plagiarizing another answer, that should be
>   flagged and removed. If a user copies an answer just to say "Thanks,
>   that solved it", that should be flagged and removed. However, if a
>   user decides to restate another answer in the form that worked for
>   them (what appears to be the case here), that's not something that
>   should be flagged. They also have no obligation to accept any
>   particular answer, or to maintain acceptance of any answer.

[What do you do when the OP copies your answer and posts it as his own?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266415/what-do-you-do-when-the-op-copies-your-answer-and-posts-it-as-his-own?noredirect=1#comment65581_266416)

Comment: Oh, the delicious irony.

Comment: Using this logic you could answer every question you ask with your own answer, and never give credit to whomever helped you find a solution.

Comment: Reworking an answer so that it fully meets the asker's requirements and reposting it as the final solution is perfectly OK.  In practice, it doesn't happen all that often.

Comment: I read that, yes. But does simply changing arbitrary selector or variable names in the code qualify as reworking? If the core functionality remains unchanged then shouldn't the credit go to the answer that provided the solution? Would it not be more proper to edit the accepted answer rather than replace it with a significantly similar one?

Comment: In general, I'm not a big fan of changing the meaning of other people's answers.

Answer (score 0):

In such cases what you should do is flag a moderator. So click on the `flag` option, select
*other (needs ♦ moderator attention)* and than just type the reason why you flagged the post, something like

[image]

Comment: Exactly what would a moderator do about this?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Can delete the answer which is copied by the user?

Comment: Why do I need to get involved with that?  Vote down the answer, if you believe the OP is being redundant.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Because the mantra is flag, flag, flag.

Comment: technically the user cheated, he switched the tick to his answer, so why not just delete it when we can clearly see that the user is playing foul?

Comment: @staticx: Well, let me clarify that.  You should flag for moderator attention if something bad is happening that the community cannot take care of itself.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Exactly, community cannot delete the answer as user has switched the tick, I don't agree with you on this..

Comment: @Mr.Alien: Well the motto has always been it's the answer that solved the user's problem. Regardless how wrong that decision may be

Comment: @staticx sorry but this is wrong, its like, I ask a question, get an answer, I copy the answer, repost it, and tick mark my own, is that how we play here?

Comment: It would have to actually be a copy first.  I don't think that's the case here.

Comment: @Mr.Alien: He didn't copy it.. he made a different answer albeit a bad one

Comment: @staticx I answered before op contributed the link, also, am not answering specific to this one, rather a general scenario

Comment: @Mr.Alien: Not sure what benefit that would bring. At any rate, the community can handle it. No need to involve a moderator.

Comment: If a user is word-for-word plagiarizing another answer, that should be flagged and removed. If a user copies an answer just to say "Thanks, that solved it", that should be flagged and removed. However, if a user decides to restate another answer in the form that worked for them (what appears to be the case here), that's not something that should be flagged. They also have no obligation to accept any particular answer, or to maintain acceptance of any answer.

Answer (score 0):

The summation I get from the comments left in the other answers to this question is

**No**, it is not acceptable for a poster to completely plagiarize your answer and accept it as their own, **but** it may be acceptable for them to post an answer that is significantly similar to the answer you have given—even if plagiarized in part—and accept their own answer. Ultimately, it is up to the community, or a moderator to decide.

The community can decide by giving your answer the upvotes instead of the OP, a moderator can decide by deleting the OP's answer.

If you feel your answer has been plagiarized completely or in part, all you can do is flag a moderator, and they will be the judge.

Comment: In general, mods don't get involved in these kinds of disputes, unless they are egregious.  The community already has downvotes and delete votes available to them for answers that they feel are substandard in some way.

Comment: Could you provide an example of what constitutes an egregious dispute?